# Prove the hyperbolic paraboloid $xy = z$ intersects its tangent plane in two perpendicular lines

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, solution-verification, proof-writing, surfaces

Prove that the hyperbolic paraboloid $z = xy$ and its tangent plane at an arbitrary point intersect in two perpendicular lines. *(Source: Based on Shifrin's Multivariable Mathematics.)*

My solution is below.  I request verification and critique.  In particular: Is the solution written well? How could the exposition be improved? I tried to make the solution clear and direct while still capturing the process I used to get there.

---

Let $(a,b,c)$ be an arbitrary point on the surface.  At that point, the surface has Jacobian $\begin{bmatrix}b & a & -1\end{bmatrix}$, so the tangent plane is $$b(x-a) + a(y-b) - (z-c) = 0.$$  The intersection of the surface and its tangent is then described by this system of equations:

$$\begin{align}
xy &= z \tag{1}\\
bx + ay -z - 2ab + c &= 0 \tag{2}\\
ab &= c \tag{3}
\end{align}$$

Equation $(1)$ describes the surface and $(2)$ the tangent plane; $(x,y,z)$ is on their intersection iff it is a solution to both.  But the tangent plane must be tangent to a *point on the surface*, which is a constraint provided by $(3)$.

Substituting, we reduce these to a single equation $$xy = bx + ay - ab \tag{4}.$$ Recalling that $(x-a)(y-b) = xy - bx - ay + ab$, we reduce $(4)$ to simply $$(x-a)(y-b) = 0$$ giving solutions $$[x = a, z = ay] \lor [y =b, z = bx].$$

Thus, the intersection is two perpendicular lines (parameterized by $t$): $$(a, t, at) \\(t, b, bt).$$

Comment: The exercise never said perpendicular :) Other than that, I would complain about your second sentence. A surface does not have a Jacobian. You should actually take the step of defining $f(x,y,z) = xy - z$, and then $Df(a,b,c) = ...$. And, of course, you never checked that the lines are perpendicular — they most certainly are not.

Comment: You get the same tangent plane whether you do it implicitly or explicitly. I’m objecting to your language: A function has a derivative; a surface does not. What function are you associating to a surface? Regarding angles, do you really think that projection is angle-preserving? Compute the dot product of the direction vectors of these lines!

Comment: You have not specified a defining function, so, no. Reread my first comment.

Comment: That is just way too complicated. You have lines with direction vectors $(1,0,b)$ and $(0,1,a)$. So the angle between them is $\arccos\big(\frac{ab}{\sqrt{(1+a^2)(1+b^2)}}\big)$.

Comment: @TedShifrin My goal in [working out the general case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4728270/when-two-perpendicular-lines-are-rotated-about-each-other-out-of-their-common-p) wasn't just to find the angle _here_, but to solve the general problem of rotating lines (which came up from this discussion).  It's an interesting problem, as (as evidenced by the comments there]) it's easy to assume the lines will retain their same angle.

Comment: I don't understand. Rotating and projecting are two totally different animals.

Comment: @TedShifrin You can get $(a, t, at), (t, b, bt)$ by two rotations, as described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4728270/when-two-perpendicular-lines-are-rotated-about-each-other-out-of-their-common-p) , depending of course on what $a$ and $b$ are.  I wanted to understand when, if ever, those rotations would preserve orthogonality, and found that they _never_ would, unless one was a null rotation.